# scrapy gives twisted error: AttributeError: __enter__

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted

I'm trying to use scrapy for something relatively simple:

`scrapy shell https://www.highsociety.fr/robots.txt`

However, this gives me the following error:

```py
twisted.web._newclient.RequestGenerationFailed: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure builtins.AttributeError: __enter__>]
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, any idea is greatly appreciated
Thanks a lot

Comment: Works fine on my end, might be some issue with your installation. Run `pip3 install scrapy --force --upgrade` to reinstall scrapy. See if it works after that

Answer (score 0):

Okay, looks like this was an error with pyopenssl, fixed it by uninstalling and reinstalling it again ...