# Scrapy error "twisted.web._newclient.RequestGenerationFailed"

Tags: python, scrapy, pyinstaller

In `Pycharm venv`, I have created a gui with `pyinstaller`, which calls `scrapy` on a file with `Popen`. From terminal `Popen` was calling `scrapy` and scraping was being done successfully. After packing gui was being opened but stderr of Popen was telling `scrapy not found`. A issue I opened on [Githubissue](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/7067) helped me to find out that `pyinstaller`was using the `user` package instead of `venv`. I solved it by installing scrapy for the `user` and after packing with `pyinstaller` the built `gui` is calling scrapy. Still don't know why `pyinstaller` didn't use `venv` package.

But now I am getting scrapy error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 62, in run
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 49, in process_request
    return (yield download_func(request=request, spider=spider))
twisted.web._newclient.RequestGenerationFailed: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure builtins.AttributeError: __enter__>]
```

Even if I run scrapy as user (outside venv), in terminal I get this error. Inside `venv` running in terminal things are fine.

Also is it the ideal way to pack from `pyinstaller` i.e. installing packages in user as well, so that `pyinstaller` can get them?

Gui code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox as tkms
from tkinter import ttk
import shlex
from subprocess import Popen
import json


def get_url():
    #printing Entry url to a file


harvest = None


def watch():
    global harvest
    if harvest:
        if harvest.poll() != None:
            # Update your progressbar to finished.
            progress_bar.stop()
            #if harvest finishes OK then show confirmation message otherwise show error.
            if harvest.returncode == 0:
                mes = tkms.showinfo(title='progress', message='Scraping Done')
                if mes == 'ok':
                    root.destroy()
            else:
                tkms.showinfo(title='Error', message=f'harvest returncode == {harvest.returncode}')

        harvest = None

        else:
            # indicate that process is running.
            progress_bar.grid()
            progress_bar.start(10)
            root.after(100, watch)


def scrape():
    global harvest
    command_line = shlex.split('scrapy runspider ./scrape.py')
    with open ('stdout.txt', 'wb') as out, open('stderr', 'wb') as err:
        harvest = Popen(command_line, stdout=out, stderr=err)
    watch()


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Title")

url = tk.StringVar(root)

entry1 = tk.Entry(root, width=90, textvariable=url)
entry1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)

my_button = tk.Button(root, text="Process", command=lambda: [get_url(), scrape()])
my_button.grid(row=2, column=2)

progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=300, mode='indeterminate')
progress_bar.grid(row=3, column=2)
progress_bar.grid_forget()

root.mainloop()
```

Scrapy reproducable code

```
import scrapy
import json


class ImgSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'img'

    #allowed_domains = [user_domain]
    start_urls = ['xyz']

    def parse(self, response):
        title = response.css('img::attr(alt)').getall()
        links = response.css('img::attr(src)').getall()

        with open('../images/urls.txt', 'w') as f:
            for i in title:
                f.write(i)
            f.close
```

Comment: My comment is the same.  Please create a [example].  You are always better off using a virtual environment though.

Comment: I have put reproducible codes for both files. Please have a look.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66580530/13100522) answer suggests problem is related with pyopenssl. I checked and I don't have it installed. without sudo, pip was giving error for a path in usr/bin. So I ran `sudo pip install pyopenssl` this gives error `can't find rust compiler` I installed rust compiler as suggested [here](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install) with sudo. I again tried to install pyopenssl. Despite rust being installed I am still gettng `rust compiler error`

Comment: I got it to work  although i never encountered the error you cite in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work.

Steps to reproduce...

Open a new directory and start a new python virtual enviornment, and update pip install scrapy and install pyinstaller into the virtual environement.

In the new directory create the the two python scripts... mine is `main.py` and `scrape.py`

**main.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox as tkms
from tkinter import ttk
import shlex
import os
import scrapy
from subprocess import Popen
import json

def get_path(name):
    return os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),name).replace("\\","/")

harvest = None

def watch():
    global harvest
    if harvest:
        if harvest.poll() != None:
            # Update your progressbar to finished.
            progress_bar.stop()
            #if harvest finishes OK then show confirmation message otherwise show error.
            if harvest.returncode == 0:
                mes = tkms.showinfo(title='progress', message='Scraping Done')
                if mes == 'ok':
                    root.destroy()
            else:
                tkms.showinfo(title='Error', message=f'harvest returncode == {harvest.returncode}')

        harvest = None

    else:
        # indicate that process is running.
        progress_bar.grid()
        progress_bar.start(10)
        root.after(100, watch)


def scrape():
    global harvest
    command_line = shlex.split('scrapy runspider ' + get_url('scrape.py'))
    with open ('stdout.txt', 'wb') as out, open('stderr.txt', 'wb') as err:
        harvest = Popen(command_line, stdout=out, stderr=err)
    watch()


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Title")

url = tk.StringVar(root)

entry1 = tk.Entry(root, width=90, textvariable=url)
entry1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)

my_button = tk.Button(root, text="Process", command=scrape)
my_button.grid(row=2, column=2)

progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=300, mode='indeterminate')
progress_bar.grid(row=3, column=2)
progress_bar.grid_forget()

root.mainloop()
```

**scrape.py**

```
import scrapy
import os

class ImgSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'img'

    #allowed_domains = [user_domain]
    start_urls = ['https://www.bbc.com/news/in_pictures']  # i just used this for testing.

    def parse(self, response):
        title = response.css('img::attr(alt)').getall()
        links = response.css('img::attr(src)').getall()

        if not os.path.exists('./images'):
            os.makedirs('./images')
        with open('./images/urls.txt', 'w') as f:
            for i in title:
                f.write(i)
            f.close
        yield {"title": title, "links": links}
```

Then run `pyinstaller -F main.py`, which will then generate a `main.spec` file.  open that and make these changes to the file.

**main.spec**

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None
import os

scrape = "scrape.py"
imagesdir = "images"  

a = Analysis(
    ['main.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[(scrape,'.'), (imagesdir,'.')],  # add these lines
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='main',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=True,  # Once you have confirmed it is working you can set this to false
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
```

Then once that is all done. go back to your terminal and run pyinstaller main.spec, and bobs your uncle...

---

#### Update

main.py  -

> I essentially just removed the `shlex` portion and made the path to scrape.py relative to the main.py file path.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox as tkms
from tkinter import ttk
from subprocess import Popen
import json
import os


def get_url():
    print('Getting URL...')
    data = url.get()
    if not os.path.exists('./data'):
        os.makedirs('./data')
    with open('./data/url.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f)

harvest = None

def watch():
    global harvest
    print('watch started')
    if harvest:
        if harvest.poll() != None:
            print('progress bar ends')
            # Update your progressbar to finished.
            progress_bar.stop()
            #if harvest finishes OK then show confirmation message otherwise show error.
            if harvest.returncode == 0:
                mes = tkms.showinfo(title='progress', message='Scraping Done')
                if mes == 'ok':
                    root.destroy()
            else:
                tkms.showinfo(title='Error', message=f'harvest returncode == {harvest.returncode}')

            # Maybe report harvest.returncode?
            print(f'harvest return code if Poll !None =--######==== {harvest.returncode}')
            print(f'harvest poll =--######==== {harvest.poll}')
            # Re-schedule `watch` to be called again after 0.1 s.
            harvest = None

        else:
            # indicate that process is running.
            print('progress bar starts')
            progress_bar.grid()
            progress_bar.start(10)
            print(f'harvest return code =--######==== {harvest.returncode}')
            root.after(100, watch)


def scrape():
    global harvest
    scrapefile = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'scrape.py')
    # harvest = Popen(command_line)
    with open ('stdout.txt', 'wb') as out, open('stderr.txt', 'wb') as err:
        # harvest = Popen('scrapy runspider ./scrape.py', stdout=out, stderr=err, shell=True)
        harvest = Popen(["python3", scrapefile], stdout=out, stderr=err)
        out.close(), err.close()
    print('harvesting started')
    watch()


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Title")

url = tk.StringVar(root)

entry1 = tk.Entry(root, width=90, textvariable=url)
entry1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)

my_button = tk.Button(root, text="Process", command=lambda: [get_url(), scrape()])
my_button.grid(row=2, column=2)

progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=300, mode='indeterminate')
progress_bar.grid(row=3, column=2)
progress_bar.grid_forget()

root.mainloop()
```

main.spec

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
block_cipher = None
a = Analysis(['main.py'], pathex=[], binaries=[],
    datas=[('scrape.py','.')],   # <------- this is the only change that I made
    hiddenimports=[], hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={}, runtime_hooks=[], excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False, win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher, noarchive=False,)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz, a.scripts, a.binaries, a.zipfiles, a.datas, [],
    name='main', debug=False, bootloader_ignore_signals=False, strip=False,
    upx=True, upx_exclude=[], runtime_tmpdir=None, console=False,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False, argv_emulation=False, target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None, entitlements_file=None,)
```

I made no changes to the scrape.py

Comment: Created new venv, installed pip, updated it, installed scrapy, and pyinstaller. I have implemented and copied the code shown over here, instead of mine (to see if things get to work). The gui is doing nothing (Progressbar is not bouncing, previously it was) and scrapy is also not running. How is it working at your end?

Comment: @MayankMishra well the progress bar was not working on my end either I didn't know it was supposed too but scrapy was working fine... Ill post a logifile to show you

Comment: in the code line 40 `'get_url' is not defined` error was coming so I removed that and placed like before (which was working) `command_line = shlex.split('scrapy runspider ./scrape.py')` Did that has to do something with mine not working?

Comment: Mine is also working now. I don't know what has suddenly happened? Can you suggest what's wrong with the progressbar now. And the reason packed executable has started working and not working before? Did new venv did something interesting? And many thanks for putting your efforts & time to solve the problem. Accepting it as the answer.

Comment: The progress bar never worked for me... But Ill take a look.

Comment: With my code I am getting the same Error. To dig down, I have even created a standalone spider and created executable for scrape only, which is running fine, means scrapy itself is fine while packing. The only thing that missed in the reproducible codes was writing url to file (in gui) and reading it in scrape.

I have shared both the codes. Can you please run after packing & see if you are also getting the same error with full code or is it just me?
[Gui](https://paste.pythondiscord.com/yoyicujexu)
[scrape](https://paste.pythondiscord.com/oyunoluqur). And thanks for your efforts

Comment: what is it you are actually trying to do with scrapy?  Your code doesn't really make sense... unless what your trying to do is just get all of the image links and names from a specific page and write them to a text file...  In which case there are better ways of doing this... another question is why do you want to run the crawler in a subprocess anyway?

Comment: @MayankMishra  I got it to work this  please see the bottom of my answer the UPDATE portion... Then just run pyinstall main.spec  and it should work flwalessly... progressbar and all

Comment: Yes mine is running with this. I am not getting why it was not running, only shlex is replaced. Regarding code usage-In the next parse I am saving all the images. Didn't include the next and subsequent parse functions as it wd have been unnecessary over here making the post only longer. Regarding using subprocess - I tried with `multiprocessing` but it didn't run. Running the whole code is still giving me the same error. gui I am using yours. In spec adding the scrape. Scrape is [shared](https://hastebin.com/noxeqojako.py). Can you please pack this one and see whether its working?

Comment: I have made it work with `multiprocessing`. Will update about the packed status.

Comment: gui is also working with multiprocessing. Thanks for all the efforts you have put to solve the problem.